# Stabilizers must be of the same order

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a group acting on a set $X$. Let $x,y \in X$ be from the same orbit.
I managed to prove that $\mathrm{Stab}(x)$ and $\mathrm{Stab}(y)$ are conjugates.
But how to deduce from this that $\mathrm{Stab}(x)$ and $\mathrm{Stab}(y)$ have the same order?

Could we just rely on the fact that each element from $\mathrm{Stab}(x)$ have a conjugate element with the same order from $\mathrm{Stab}(y)$?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, you've shown that $\mathrm{Stab}(x)$ and $\mathrm{Stab}(y)$ are conjugate subgroups of $G$, i.e., there exists some element $g\in G$ for which $\mathrm{Stab}(x)=g^{-1}\mathrm{Stab}(y)g$.

Now, prove that the function $c_g:G\to G$ defined by $c_g(h)=g^{-1}hg$ is a bijection, so that $\mathrm{Stab}(x)$ and its image under $c_g$, namely $\mathrm{Stab}(y)$, must have the same cardinality. (Note: such a function is known as an **inner automorphism** of $G$, [see on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_automorphism).)